# mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com update regular hours

Tags: php, google-api, google-my-business-api

I'm trying to update regular hours with the new Google My Business Api v1, I make a 'PATCH' request with php curl, the API doesn't return any error, but from my Business Place the regular Hours are cleared, what I'm doing wrong..
I try to find a request model but i can't find anything for the new Google My Business API

Code:

```
$timePeriods = json_decode("[{
    "openDay": "MONDAY",
    "openTime": {
        "hours": 6,
        "minutes": 0
    },
    "closeDay": "MONDAY",
    "closeTime": {
        "hours": 20,
        "minutes": 30
    }
}, {
    "openDay": "TUESDAY",
    "openTime": {
        "hours": 6,
        "minutes": 0
    },
    "closeDay": "TUESDAY",
    "closeTime": {
        "hours": 19,
        "minutes": 45
    }
}, {
    "openDay": "WEDNESDAY",
    "openTime": {
        "hours": 6,
        "minutes": 0
    },
    "closeDay": "WEDNESDAY",
    "closeTime": {
        "hours": 20,
        "minutes": 15
    }
}, {
    "openDay": "THURSDAY",
    "openTime": {
        "hours": 6,
        "minutes": 0
    },
    "closeDay": "THURSDAY",
    "closeTime": {
        "hours": 12,
        "minutes": 30
    }
}, {
    "openDay": "THURSDAY",
    "openTime": {
        "hours": 13,
        "minutes": 30
    },
    "closeDay": "THURSDAY",
    "closeTime": {
        "hours": 19,
        "minutes": 0
    }
}, {
    "openDay": "FRIDAY",
    "openTime": {
        "hours": 8,
        "minutes": 0
    },
    "closeDay": "FRIDAY",
    "closeTime": {
        "hours": 19,
        "minutes": 0
    }
}]");


$ch = curl_init('https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/locations/'.$BID.'?'.http_build_query($queryParams));


$jsonDataEncoded = [];
$jsonDataEncoded['regularHours'] = Array(
    'periods' => $timePeriods
);    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $GMB_API->getAccessToken(),
));

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH"); //1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Set the content type to application/json
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Where **$BID** are the place id.

Comment: Does $queryParams include updateMask=regularHours?

Comment: Yes! I miss this part of code: 
`$updateMask = Array('regularHours');
$queryParams = Array('updateMask' => implode(',', $updateMask));`

Comment: Are you able to modify the regular hours of that location via the GMB UI?

Comment: In some special cases (e.g. critical infrastructure), Google does not allow editing of certain protected fields - this would usually be visible via the UI but not be transparent over the API.

Comment: You could try the OAuth playground (https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request) to rule out an API bug.

Comment: I Add to the header 'X-GOOG-API-FORMAT-VERSION: 2' and now give me this error: "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project." How I can do this request with oAuth2??